# SQL Server Data Import using a .sql extension dump

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to import a 15 gb .sql extension dump in SQL Server 2012. 
I tried the import using sqlcmd command line utility but the dump import failed after importing around 2gbs of data. I didnt find any syntax error in the dump file.
I tried this command to `import sqlcmd -S (Server) -d (database) -i (filename)`
So i have a couple of questions:

1. Is there another utility from which i can import .sql extension db dump
2. Is there a limitation on sqlcmd in importing large dumps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what file system are you using? Fat32? NTFS? the 2 gb just raises a flag regarding max file size on certain file systems

Comment: Any other suggestion , as to how i should proceed with the import.

Answer (score 0):

There's [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) command line utility. It also comes with SQL Server and it's located in Tools\Binn

Command syntax is

```
osql –H <workstation_name> -S <server_name[\instance_name]> -U <user_login_ID> -P <login_password> –i <full_path_to_script>
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should use `SQLCMD` in place of `osql / isql` which are deprecated and don't support all features of SQL Server 2005 and newer